# Inline change input arguement by a function, not by using class method

Tags: python, function, inline

Try to define a function to inline update input arguments, but doesn't find the way to go.

For example,

```py
def swap(a, b):
    # Result here not return to arguments after called
    a, b = b, a

a, b = 5, 3
swap(a, b)    # Expect a=3, b=5 after call swap
```

My question is how to define the function, not different way to call `swap` or class method. Python does not support call by reference, maybe no way for it.

Comment: Python does not support call by reference, this isn't possible with a function.

Comment: Yes, I also think so, but try to find the exact answer if it is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "exact answer?" It's not possible, and really, not desirable. The caller shouldn't expect names in it's local namespace to be mutated by a function. There's a reason a lot of modern languages don't support this

Comment: Or just to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are immutable objects.
Thus, when you pass them into the function, all that gets changed are the local references.  There is nothing you can do to make the function alter the values of the main-program variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: can `globals()` object be useful to change the values defined in the `main()` function?

Comment: Hope to call it anywhere, not just under `main()`

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia well, that's one way. If you only want to affect global values, a `global` statement would work

Comment: Actually, they *type* of the objects involved is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The way to return a variable from a function is by calling `return`. For example,

```py
def swap(a, b):
    a, b = b, a
    return a, b
a, b = swap(b, a)
```

This seems entirely pointless, though. For something like this, it would be better to just do it outside the function.

```py
a, b = 5, 3
a, b = b, a
```

If you really needed to change the variables inside a function, and you knew what they were referred to outside the function, you could use the `global` keyword.

```py
a, b = 5, 3
def swap(): # No parameters necessary.
    global a
    global b
    a, b = b, a
swap()
```

Comment: Your last solution would throw an error because you can't use keyword global on parameters.

Comment: `return` statement not inline update variable, in my question, I want to calll `swap` only. not specified variables, not direct swap variable, but by calling function.

Comment: I didn't know that, but I guess it makes sense. Edited for clarity.

Comment: @JasonYang it's not possible in general. Python does not support call by reference

Comment: Solutions your provided all not for my question, but still thank you.